# blender animate/ move object with csv file data python

Tags: python, csv, blender, animated

I want to use blender to open up a csv file and use the motion data in that file to animate an object or hand Is there python code to do this

Answer (score 2):

Probably not, but it would be trivial to write something to do it. Import [Python's `csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html), then use the data you read to update an [object's `location`](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.types.Object.html#bpy.types.Object.location) when the [frame changes](http://www.blender.org/api/blender_python_api_2_74_5/bpy.app.handlers.html#bpy.app.handlers.frame_change_post). Or you could transfer the data to an animation curve.

This question might be better asked on the [Blender Stack Exchange site](https://blender.stackexchange.com/).